# Dejar de usar Android X

Tags: android, android-studio

Estaba utilizando una versión anterior de android studio(creo que la 3.4), y actualicé a la versión 4.0. El problema es que tras actualizar, al importar librerías(por ejemplo para manejar fragment que es lo que más problemas me está dando)me las importa automáticamente como:

```
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

en vez de:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

que es lo que necesito actualmente ya que mi profesor no utiliza android x para nada y esto me supone un problema a la hora de importar estas librerías y sobre todo de tipos de datos que no son iguales los de android x que los anteriores de android y no sé como solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Los tipos de datos no cambian, comenta a tu profesor que Android Studio sugiere usar las ùltimas versiones de dependencias para beneficio de las aplicaciones, en este caso [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?hl=es) reemplaza por completo las bibliotecas de compatibilidad asì como las primeras versiones previas a Android 3.0 y se debe usar ya que de esta forma puedes implementar la arquitectura que se recomienda actualmente para crear Apps Android.

De hecho se recomienda migrar tus proyectos a Android X

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas usar:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

en lugar de

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

**No es recomendable** , pero tendrìas que instalar una versiòn 3.4 o anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, la verdad que es criterio del profesor y ya, no es para nada lo más correcto.
Lo que me ha funcionado para dejar de usar androidx es: Al crear un nuevo proyecto marcar la opción de: "Use legacy android.support libraries".